# How to add a behavior to an existing AWS cloudfront distribution for an API gateway using AWS CDK (typescript preferred)?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cdk

I am trying to implement a CDK project that will deploy a static website in an s3 bucket along with a CloudFront distribution. I also have an API gateway that I need to access via the same cloud-front URL. I am able to do this from the AWS Management console. But when I try to implement this using CDK, I am getting circular dependency errors.

```js
    const cdn = new cloudfront.Distribution(this, "websitecdn", {
        defaultBehavior: {origin: new origins.S3Origin(s3_bucket)}
    });
    const api = new apigw.RestApi(this, 'someapi', {defaultCorsPreflightOptions: enableCors})
    const loginApi = api.root.addResource('login', {defaultCorsPreflightOptions: enableCors})
    loginApi.addMethod('POST', new apigw.LambdaIntegration(loginLambda, {
    proxy: false,
    integrationResponses: [LambdaIntegrationResponses]}), 
    {
        methodResponses: [LambdaMethodResponses]
    })
    const apiOrigin = new origins.RestApiOrigin(api)
    cdn.addBehavior("/prod/*",apiOrigin,{
        allowedMethods: cloudfront.AllowedMethods.ALLOW_ALL,
        cachePolicy: cloudfront.CachePolicy.CACHING_DISABLED,
        viewerProtocolPolicy: ViewerProtocolPolicy.HTTPS_ONLY,
    })
```

Everything works fine until I try to add the behavior for the API gateway in the CDN. But when I add that, it starts throwing circular dependency errors.

What I am trying to do using AWS CDK typescript:

1. deploy a static s3 website
2. create a CloudFront Distribution for this website -> let's call it cdn_x
3. deploy backend API (Lambda functions with API Gateway)
4. Add the API gateway URL as a behavior to cdn_x so that I can use the same URL for API calls as well (I do not have a custom domain)

I was expecting the deployment to go through fine as I was able to go it in the AWS management console (Web UI of AWS). But trying to do the same using AWS CDK throws circular dependency errors.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear from your example how the stacks and resources in your CDK project are created and related. I'm unable to use your code examples.

In the meantime, I created a TypeScript example using Multiple Behaviors in CloudFront with Amazon API Gateway under the `/api/*` path and a S3 bucket as default behavior to serve static assets `/*`

The final CDK structure is the following:

[image]

The CDK codebase uses [multiple stacks](https://github.com/oieduardorabelo/cdk-cloudfront-behavior-api-gateway-waf-protection/tree/main/lib):

- `cloudfront-stack.ts`
- `rest-api-stack.ts`
- `s3-stack.ts`
- `waf-stack.ts`

And resources are passed as references in [`bin/infra.ts`](https://github.com/oieduardorabelo/cdk-cloudfront-behavior-api-gateway-waf-protection/blob/main/bin/infra.ts)

```js
const app = new cdk.App();
const s3Stack = new S3Stack(app, "S3Stack");
const restApiStack = new RestApiStack(app, "RestApiStack");
const wafStack = new WafStack(app, "WafStack", {
  restApi: restApiStack.restApi,
});
const cloudFrontStack = new CloudFrontStack(app, "CloudFrontStack", {
  bucketAssets: s3Stack.bucketAssets,
  restApi: restApiStack.restApi,
  wafCloudFrontAclArn: wafStack.wafCloudFrontAclArn,
  wafRestApiOriginVerifyHeader: wafStack.wafRestApiOriginVerifyHeader,
  wafRestApiOriginVerifyHeaderValue: wafStack.wafRestApiOriginVerifyHeaderValue,
});
```

GitHub repository:

- https://github.com/oieduardorabelo/cdk-cloudfront-behavior-api-gateway-waf-protection

I trust the example above will clarity some of your questions.